# How to handle a "First Chance exception" in Visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to make a pointer of the user class and assign it to the address of Teacher or Staff. I have been trying to fix this error for a long time, I couldn't;

```
int userType;
User *U=NULL;
string ID, password;
cout << "Please select user type for login -> 1 : Teacher, 2 : Staff : ";
cin >> userType;
cout << endl << "Please key in your ID : ";
cin >> ID;
cout << endl << "Please key in your password : ";
cin >> password;
if (userType == 1){
    U = new Teacher();
    try{
        U->Login(ID, password);
    }
    catch (std::ifstream::failure e){
        cerr << "Exception opening file" << endl;
    }
}
else if (userType == 2){

    U = new Staff();
    try{
        U->Login(ID, password);
    }
    catch (std::ifstream::failure e){
        cerr << "Exception opening file" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which exception and where?

Comment: The exception occurs after entering the password

Comment: @MohammedShafras , provide a minimal code to reproduce your error.

Answer (score 0):

The first chance exception message is displayed when an exception is thrown, not necessarily if it is not caught; thus if you are catching it (or the library is), you can generally ignore it.

If it was unexpected in terms of your code and application, then you can break on the "first chance exception" and debug as to why it was thrown in the first place.

---

As a note on the code sample;

- The general advice is that exceptions are generally thrown by value and caught by reference.

  ```
  catch (std::ifstream::failure e) {
  ```

  Should be

  ```
  catch (std::ifstream::failure& e) {
  ```
- You could/should add a general catch all, this may help with debugging. Thus add

  ```
  catch (std::exception& e) {
    // ... e.what()
  }
  catch (...) {
    // ...
  }
  ```
- Given the context of the code `U->Login(ID, password);` Does that use streams at some point (and stream exceptions enabled), if not, catching a stream error would probably not work anyway.

Comment: I have changed the catch block parameter to "exception e", I am having the same error

Comment: @MohammedShafras, you have include the necessary headers?

Comment: Can I know which headers do I need to include?

Comment: @MohammedShafras. The first chance exception is thrown in the compiled code, so if the code compiles, you have included (somehow) everything needed. To know what to include, you need to refer to a good C++ reference to find the required include for each library facility used (such as cppreference.com)